# Correlation heating map not sorted in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a newbie with R. Here is my problem, I am trying to plot a correlation heatmap with ggplot2 but I don't know what's happening here.

**The piece of code is working properly...**

```
colnames(data)[2] = paste("x_",100+i,sep="")

    > head(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA)
          N1    N2 Correlation
    1  x_101 x_101   1.0000000
    20 x_101 x_102   0.9816180
    21 x_102 x_102   1.0000000
    39 x_101 x_103   0.9579376
    40 x_102 x_103   0.9059575
    41 x_103 x_103   1.0000000
```

[image]

**The piece of code that is not working...**

```
strColName = paste(substring(dataName,1,2),i,sep="")
colnames(data)[2] = strColName

> head(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA)
   N1 N2 Correlation
1  E1 E1   1.0000000
20 E1 Y2   0.9816180
21 Y2 Y2   1.0000000
39 E1 T3   0.9579376
40 Y2 T3   0.9059575
41 T3 T3   1.0000000
```

[image]

I don't know what i am missing something when i try to change column names before plotting.

**Solved. Thanks to Nathan Day. I added this two new lines and works perfectly**

```
matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N1<-factor(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N1, levels = unique(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N1), order=TRUE)
matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N2<-factor(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N2, levels = unique(matrizCorrMeltedNoNA$N2), order=TRUE)
```

Comment: when you change the colnames, R no longer sees ordered `x_101, x_102` values, instead it is seeing characters  `B1, E1` and is using an alphabetical sort method, this is where `factor()` comes in to define `levels` or an order for your variable

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan, solved. Updated.

Comment: `order = TRUE` is unnecessary. All factors have orders for their levels, the `order = TRUE` is only needed if you want a particular type of contrast for the factor when modeling.